# Remote Docker Host Authentication

Tags: ssl, docker

Hi I'm currently working on a side project. In this project I'll have a central server that will need to connect to several remote docker daemons. My problem is with authentication.

Given that the project will be hosted on Digitalocean, my first thought suggested that I'll accept only connections from the private networking interface. The problem is that that interface is accessible by all other servers in the same datacenter.

Second thought is to allow only requests from the central server using the DOCKER_HOST config, the problem is that if I understand correctly the if the private IP of the centeral server get known, the IP can be spoofed.

Third thought is to enable TLS ( https://docs.docker.com/articles/https/ ), I've never dealt with those things before and the tutorial is unclear for me, I lack the knowledge of the terminologies and it's being used heavily.

So basically the problem is that I have a central client and multiple remote docker hosts, what is the best way to connect to them? Thank you.

EDIT: I managed to solve the problem using HTTP authentication by running nginx as a proxy in front of the docker daemon.

Answer (score 0):

My understand is you are trying to build a docker cluster, which can manage all nodes from one single central server.

this is very likely docker's [Docker Swarm](https://docs.docker.com/swarm/) project, from their doc, they give some simple idea how this is work:

> - open a TCP port on each node for communication with the swarm manager
> - install Docker on each node
> - create and manage TLS certificates to secure your swarm

Sorry this should post as a comment but I do not have enough rep to do that.

Comment: Yeah I know docker swarm, it's still in beta and I don't need all of its features. Also using swarm I'll mange the TLS things myself, which is basically the same problem I already have.